# Accessing $scope date inside a http.get callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to store the data returned by `$http.get` in a `$scope` variable to be used by my `ui-grid` control.

I´m sure I´m missing something very simple, but I can´t find out what. Here is my code:

```
app.controller('AdminUsersGridCtrl', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

    $http.get('/api/admin/user')
    .success(function (response, $scope) {
        $scope.myData = response;
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    console.log($scope.myData);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      enableFiltering: true,
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'firstName' },
        { field: 'lastName' },
        { field: 'jobTitle'},
        {
          field: 'email',
          filter: {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.ENDS_WITH,
            placeholder: 'ends with'
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'phone',
          filter: {
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
              return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    };        

  });
```

My console inside success prints `undefined`. How can I access the original `$scope` inside the `$http.get success` function ?

Comment: You have access to it, it's just that the rest of your code is executing before the `success` because AJAX = asynchronous! Move your code to the callback

Comment: when your console logs the myData scope variable, it is indeed **undefined**, because you're still performing an **asyncronous http get request**. if you need tobind "myData" to the gridOptions and want to be 100% sure that it will be properly loaded and error-free, parse your code inside the **.success** callback, or create a `Promise` and resolve it once the http request is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My console inside success prints undefined
```

But, your console is NOT inside the success method. This is inside:

```
$http.get('/api/admin/user')
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.myData = response;
    console.log($scope.myData);
})
.error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

This is not:

```
// order of events..
// #1...first $http
$http.get('/api/admin/user')
.success(function (response) {
    //... #3 third. Now finally response is defined. the end
    $scope.myData = response;
})
.error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

//... #2 second. $scope.myData definitely IS undefined
console.log($scope.myData);
```

Huge difference. There is also no need to include `$scope` in your success callback. I've never seen that before. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Obvious. Thanks. But the $scope that I will be accessing inside the success function will be the original one (closure) ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Angular uses a digest cycle to update the view for async events, which `$http` happens to be one of

Comment: If you were changing the scope based on event that angular was not aware of (not a common use case) you would have to worry about that, and run the digest cycle manually.

Comment: There is also no need to include `$scope` into the success callback. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 0):

When is a server call is better if you use a service in an external file, but well, in your case, the $scope does not have the response because the code is executed before the service finished, try using a $timeout or something like this:

```
app.controller('AdminUsersGridCtrl', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

$http.get('/api/admin/user').success(function (response) {
    $scope.myData = response;
    fillGridOptions();
}).error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

function fillGridOptions() {
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'firstName' },
      { field: 'lastName' },
      { field: 'jobTitle' },
      {
          field: 'email',
          filter: {
              condition: uiGridConstants.filter.ENDS_WITH,
              placeholder: 'ends with'
          }
      },
      {
          field: 'phone',
          filter: {
              condition: function (searchTerm, cellValue) {
                  var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                  return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
              }
          }
      },
    ]
};
```

}

});